# Qt - Wait for Qprocess to finish

Tags: qt, command-prompt, qprocess

I'm using CMD by `QProcess` but I have a problem.

My code:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("cmd.exe");
process.write ("del f:\\b.txt\n\r");
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

When I don't pass an argument for `waitForFinished()` it waits for 30 secs. I want to terminate `QProcess` after CMD command is executed! Not much and not less!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to terminate the cmd.exe by sending `exit` command, otherwise it will wait for commands
Here is my suggestion:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("cmd.exe");
process.write ("del f:\\b.txt\n\r");
process.write ("exit\n\r");
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

The process you're starting is cmd.exe which, by itself will, not terminate. If you call cmd with arguments, you should achieve what you want: -

```
QProcess process;
process.start("cmd.exe \"del f:\\b.txt"\"");
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

Note that the arguments are escaped in quotes.

Alternatively, you could call the del process, without cmd: -

```
QProcess process;
process.start("del \"f:\\b.txt"\"");
process.waitForFinished();
process.close();
```

Finally, if you just want to delete a file, you could use the [QFile::remove](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#remove) function.

```
QFile file("f:\\b.txt");
if(file.remove())
    qDebug() << "File removed successfully";
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, as your anwser demonstrates several ways, I would add that passing -1 to QProcess::waitForFinished, would not trigger any timeout

Comment: It waits long And also did not work!
It`s a sample code. I want to use CMD for other jobs not deleting

Comment: If you're using command for other tasks, it would be easier (in my opinion) to create a script and call that from QProcess.

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani Same advice as Merlin069. Create a batch, run it as its answer show.

Comment: @jbh All thing I need it in the first post. I wnat use mentioned code and wait to finish command prpmt completion not 30secs